# How we can check that our IP is blocked by apple from using APNS service

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My apns was fine till yesterday. But today onwards am getting this error.

```
.Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)
```

I didn't change anything. I am using an adhoc distribution profile.I used apns service too many times for testing. So  i am confused about whether  apple blocked my ip.How we can check that our IP is blocked by apple from using APNS service ?

Comment: Ask them, maybe by sending an email?  I would think you'd get a different error if you were blocked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't help you check your IP addresses (well, aside from trying a new IP, or proxy), here are some things you can try to restore your APNS ability.

- I would check your push certificate. It may have expired.
- Also, look into Urban Airship. UA is a great service that helps you with using APNS. I have seen them mention Sandbox control specifically to avoid your problem of pushing the limit. (pun intended.)

**EDIT:**

Based on the last part of your error, `(Connection Timeout)`, it does not look like an IP block. It would say `(Connection refused)`.

Answer (score 1):

Which version you are using? If it is 5.2, please test with 5.3

If you are using 5.3, then please make sure whether SSL is on or off (enabled or not).